# Ошибка после обновления wordpress wp_make_content_images_responsive

Tags: wordpress, изображения

После обновления wordpress до последней версии возле изображений появилась ошибка `Deprecated: Функция wp_make_content_images_responsive с версии 5.5.0 считается устаревшей! Используйте wp_filter_content_tags(). in /data/www/c**/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4773`
Пробовал добавлять фильтр для отключения данной функции, редактировать указанный файл ( добавлять wp_filter_content_tags ) , но ничего не выходит. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Это просто предупреждение, что где-то в плагинах-темах используется устаревшая функция, которая будет удалена в следующих версиях

https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_make_content_images_responsive

```
function wp_make_content_images_responsive( $content ) {
    _deprecated_function( __FUNCTION__, '5.5.0', 'wp_filter_content_tags()' );

    // This will also add the `loading` attribute to `img` tags, if enabled.
    return wp_filter_content_tags( $content );
}
```

Если это Ваши плагины-темы - соответственно замените там функцию на wp_filter_content_tags. Если не Ваши - то обновите темы-плагины